# Deep copy without package names

Tags: java, package, deep-copy

How can I deep copy the same objects from different packages, but with the same structure without serialization?

Example:

```
package com.foo;
class Tree{
    List<Leaf> leaf;
    Int trunk;
}
```

and

```
package com.bar;
class Tree{
    List<Leaf> leaf;
    Int trunk;
}
```

both with more complex sub-objects (ArrayLists of ArrayLists).
This is basically the same object that I receive via different webservices and is therefore in different packages.

I would like to be able to "map" all different version to the same object, e.g.

Casting: `com.bar.Tree barTree = (com.foo.Tree) fooTree;`

or deep copy: `com.bar.Tree barTree = DeepCopy.(fooTree);`

With the expected result that `barTree.leaf[k] == fooTree.leaf[k]` and `barTree.trunk==fooTree.trunk`.

I could theoretically recursively copy all calues via reflection to the corresponding elements (with the same name) of the other object, but isn't there an easier way?

Edit: More complex example.

Comment: "but isn't there an easier way?" No. They are different types. That they have the same simple name and fields is merely coincidental.

Comment: You could have a look at a mapping library like dozer or even use a Json library like Jackson to serialize one object to json and deserialize that json back to another object of a different class.

Comment: Note: `barTree.leaf == fooTree.leaf` isn't a deep copy.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I know that this isnt a deep copy, this was just to show that the values should be the same.

Comment: @Thomas: For performance reasons I wanted to avoid the copying via serialization. How fast is this for large objects?

Comment: If performance is an issue you could have a look at [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org/) which seems to use a preprocessor to create the actual mapper classes and thus should be almost as fast as manually copying the values.

Comment: @Thomas: mapstruct was exactly what I was looking for. If you create an answer, I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a copy of objects of different classes whose properties match more or less you can use a mapping library like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org/). Those are quite simple to use and if the class structure is similar or even equal (i.e. the fields have the same names and types) such a mapping is generated and used with just a few lines.

Which one to use is up to you but mapstruct seems to be faster in general since it doesn't use reflection but generates classes at compile time. Here's a comparison of the two (though I must admit that I'm not sure if it is biased or not): http://mariusz.wyszomierski.pl/en/mapping-dozer-vs-mapstruct/

To be fair there are also quite a few other mapping libraries, if you're not satisfied with one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can add what is known as a copy constructor in each class that accepts as parameter an instance of the other class ex:

```
package com.foo;
class Tree{
    String leaf;
    Int trunk;
    Tree(com.bar.Tree tree){
         this.leaf = tree.leaf;
         this.trunk = tree.trunk;
    }

}
```

Then you would do the following:

```
com.bar.Tree barTree = new com.bar.Tree(fooTree);
```

Comment: But how would the copy constructor copy all the values? The example was very simple, actually there are several nested ArrayLists and complex datatypes.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the above fields are any kind of object. Simply do the same.